# Cannot find module 'src/config/twilio/config.service' from 'sms-registration.service.ts'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

That's the error I get when I fire off `npm run test`.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

and the script part of `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json -c tslint.json",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
```

Here's the jest part of `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "src"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

It seems like it doesn't like absolute paths starting with `src` but the app is compiled with no errors and it works which actually means that I don't have to modify anything in the code base, it should be th problem of tests and the `jest` configuration, I suppose.

How do I fix this error?